# Create an array of Ember.Object

Tags: ember.js, amcharts

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this basic question but frankly I can't find it on Emberjs.com nor on Stackoverflow (maybe i ask to wrong question).

I'm using amChart library to chart data. amChart requires that I pass a "standard" array of objects. So I tried to convert my Ember.object into an array with the toArray() method. But I understand that now that the toArray() method create an array of Ember.objects with the result that amChart cannot find the attributes that I mapped in amChart.

In other words, I need an array which attributes can be access by conventional javascript syntax ( array[1].attribute ) instead of 'object.get('attribute')'.

Or maybe I should take another approach to this?

**UPDATE**

From the answer below I concluded that I needed to create a new array for amChart:

```
  chartData: function() {
    var statVals = this.get('chapters.statVals');
    var statArray= statVals.toArray();
    var amCharts = [];
    var chartData = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < statArray.length; i++) {
        chartData.push({
            time: statArray[i].get('time'),
            value: statArray[i].get('value'),
        });
    }
    return chartData;
  }.property(),
```

If anyone has a more efficient / better Ember way to approach this, I would gladly modify this solution.

Comment: Got a fiddle with an example of what your data looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you have two options:

1. Avoid using computed properties in the Ember objects, as normal properties can be accessed without using `get()` ([Example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yefapowiye/1/edit?js,console)). This should work as if you were passing normal JS objects (which Ember objects are in the real sense).
2. Create a `toJsObject()` (or similar) on your objects that will convert them to normal JS objects, computed properties and all. Example:

   ```
   var Widget = Ember.Object.extend({
       toJsObject: function() {
           return {
               prop1: this.get('prop1'),
               prop2: this.get('prop2')
           };
       }
   });

   // ...

   var normalObjects = emberObjects.toArray().map(function(obj) {
       return obj.toJsObject();
   });
   ```

Comment: `return this.getProperties('prop1', 'prop2')` is cleaner.

Comment: Do you mean **without** using `get()`?